# oninput() does not fire on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am building an app using phonegap.The problem is when i run my code on browser it work perfectly fine..but oninput() dsnt fire on mobile device.
my html is :

```
            <div class="t1">09</div>
            <div class="point"><img src="img/point.png" class="dot_img"/></div>
            <div class="t2">15</div>
            <div class="point"><img src="img/point.png" class="dot_img"/></div>
            <div class="t3">am</div>
            <img src="img/round.png" class="round"/>
            <input type="time" id="timepicker" oninput="(this.blur())"/>
            </div>
```

my js is :

```
$('.time').click(function () {

$('#timepicker').focus();     

$('#timepicker').blur(function () {

    var mtime = document.getElementById("timepicker").value;


    var startHour = new Date("01/01/2007 " + mtime).getHours();

    var startMins = new Date("01/01/2007 " + mtime).getMinutes();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the change event? your js code would be the following:

```
$('.time').click(function () {
$('#timepicker').focus();     
$('#timepicker').change(function() { 
    $(this).blur();
});
$('#timepicker').blur(function () {
    var mtime = document.getElementById("timepicker").value;
    var startHour = new Date("01/01/2007 " + mtime).getHours();
    var startMins = new Date("01/01/2007 " + mtime).getMinutes();
});
```

And remove the oninput attribute on the input element of your html.